How can I create a Vec<[f64; 2]> from two Vec<f64> of the same length?
If I have two different Vec<f64> of the same length, how can I "zip" them to get a Vec<[f64; 2]> instead of a Vec<(f64, f64)>?
Here Is what I have so far:
    let vec1: Vec<f64> = vec![1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.];
    let vec2: Vec<f64> = vec![6.,5.,4.,3.,2.,1.];
    
    let zipped_vec: Vec<(&f64, &f64)> = vec1.iter().zip(vec2.iter()).collect::<Vec<_>>();

    println!("{:?}", zipped_vec); 
    //  Output: [(1.0, 6.0), (2.0, 5.0), (3.0, 4.0), (4.0, 3.0), (5.0, 2.0), (6.0, 1.0)]
    
    // If all the data is in a single Vec<f64> I found a way to do it with "chunks_exact"
    let data = vec![1.,12.,2.,23.,3.,38.,4.,44.,5.,59.,6.,71.];
            
    let graph: Vec<[f64; 2]> 
        = data.chunks_exact(2)
        .map(|x| [x[0],x[1]])
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", graph);
    // Output: [[1.0, 12.0], [2.0, 23.0], [3.0, 38.0], [4.0, 44.0], [5.0, 59.0], [6.0, 71.0]]


Link to playground
Here are some other SO threads that I looked at but they don't directly solve my issue.

Example 1
Example 2
Playground Example

 For background: I am trying to plot a line chart in egui and starting by following one of their examples that the official documentation provides here. I will provide a snippet below:
// let's create a dummy line in the plot
let graph: Vec<[f64; 2]> = vec![[0.0, 1.0], [2.0, 3.0], [3.0, 2.0]];
let inner = my_plot.show(ui, |plot_ui| {
            plot_ui.line(Line::new(PlotPoints::from(graph)).name("curve"));
            });
// Remember the position of the plot
plot_rect = Some(inner.response.rect);

You can see that PlotPoints::from() takes Vec<[f64; 2]> as an argument.
impl From<Vec<[f64; 2]>> for PlotPoints {
    fn from(coordinates: Vec<[f64; 2]>) -> Self {
        Self::new(coordinates)
    }
}


Just .map(|(&x1, &x2)| [x1, x2]) your zipped_vec before collecting⁉ Or does that not work for some reason?

It would be far more efficient to have them arranged that way to begin with. Where do the two original Vecs come from?

You should be able to collect straight into PlotPoints: https://docs.rs/egui_plot/0.27.2/egui_plot/enum.PlotPoints.html#impl-FromIterator%3C%5Bf64;+2%5D%3E-for-PlotPoints

@cafce25 great, yes this works. For Vec of smaller sizes, this works well. As @PitaJ mentioned though, this is probably inefficient for longer length datasets.

@trueequalsfalse Wow awesome I did not know that, thank you. Much more succinct

@round-and-round, it's the "keeping things in 2 separate Vecs" that's inefficient, the map should be optimized away.

You can map the iterator before collecting it directly into a PlotPoints. This works because PlotPoints implements FromIterator<[f64; 2]>.
let plot_points: PlotPoints = vec1
    .iter()
    .zip(vec2.iter())
    .map(|(x1, x2)| [*x1, *x2])
    .collect();

